# Windows 7 analog clock second hand not showing

Tags: windows-7, windows

When I click on the clock in the task bar on my Windows 7 machine (Enterprise, 64 bit) , the calendar and analog clock pop up. The analog clock has a second hand. I like that for reasons we needn't get into right now.

However, on my other Windows 7 machine (Enterprise, 32 bit), when I click the clock on the task bar, the analog clock **doesn't** show the second hand. Which I just can't handle right now for those very same reasons.

Now, in my mind, there should be a checkbox like `show seconds` or something like that somewhere but I can't for the life of me find it. (Nor was I able to find the location of this mythical checkbox/setting on-line, hence my question:

How can I make my clock show the second hand? (Or is it second*s* hand?)

To be clear, I don't want my task bar clock to show seconds, I just want the analog clock that pops up when you click on the task bar clock to show seconds.

[image: clock with and without second hand]

The picture is just an indication, this doesn't show my setup/situation. It's just a picture I found on-line showing the Windows 7 clock with and without the elusive second hand...

In response to Timmy Jim's questions:

> I've checked other machines (not used by me) and some show the seconds hand (both 64 and 32 bit) and others not, so I think this must be a setting somewhere.

Comment: This is an odd one.  Do you have any other machines with Windows 7 32 bit Enterprise on it?  I'd check to see if that one shows the second(s) hand also if you do.  That'll at least indicate if its a system thing, or machine based.

Comment: I've updated my question with the answer to you questions.