# Seconds hand missing from Windows 7 analog clock

Tags: windows-7

On some of my computers (Windows 7) the seconds hand of the analog clock is not showing. Is there a setting to change this?

This is about the analog clock that pops up when you click the clock on the task bar, not the desktop widget.

[image]
[image]

Comment: See [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/1112786/windows-7-analog-clock-second-hand-not-showing) which hasn't been answered yet.

Comment: This is strange, as it should be showing on all computers. Does this happen when booting in Safe mode? Try also using [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) to turn on "Display seconds on the task bar" found in the "Other" section of the settings.

Comment: Is there anything common between all of the computers affected (or all of the computers not affected)?  Also, do all of the computers have the same settings under Control Panel, Region and Language?

Comment: Restore these files from WinSxS folder. **1.** timedate.cpl file in System32 folder. **2.** timedate.cpl.mui file in "C:\Windows\System32\en-US\" folder if system laguage is English-US.

Comment: @Rad: You posted a bounty. It would be nice if you could comment on the suggestions above.

Comment: Does your 'Long time' format contain HH:mm:ss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried to reconstruct the problem and have come to the following result:

When connecting via `Remote Desktop` the second hand is not being displayed by default.

Even if all visual effects are enabled on the `Performance`-tab of the RDP-Connection.

There doesn't seem to be any setting or registry key to bypass this.

Tested on: Windows 7, 8 and Windows Server 2008, 2008R2, 2012, 2012R2

Comment: @Facebook Since OP does not answer any of the comments, i tried to reconstruct the problem. My answer is thus: It does not work via RDP. Perhaps this does not answer the question completely, but helps at least to understand why it happens.